# truffle migrate --network ropsten issues

Tags: truffle, dapps, truffle-migration, truffle-contract, ganache

When i run `truffle migrate --network ropsten` i don't see the contract deployment but just

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.
```

i don't know why but also deleting `./build` i can't see the deploying of my migrations files but only

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/A.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/B.sol
> Artifacts written to /Users/........./build/contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a.Emscripten.clang
```

A lot of guides show a code like this:

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
Deploying Migrations…
… 0xd01dd7...
Migrations: 0xf741...
Saving successful migration to network…
… 0x78ed...
Saving artifacts…
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
Deploying HelloWorld…
… 0x0aa9...
HelloWorld: [SAVE THIS ADDRESS!!]
Saving successful migration to network…
… 0xee95...
Saving artifacts…
```

And here my truffle.js code:

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
const MNEMONIC = 'my mnemonic words from metamask'

module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // for more about customizing your Truffle configuration!
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },

    ropsten: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, "ropsten.infura.io/v3/my-key")
      },
      network_id: 3,
      gas: 4000000      //make sure this gas allocation isn't over 4M, which is the max
    }
  }
};
```

So how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Hi there. Can you include the contents of your `truffle-config.js` file in your question?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks done, i updated the request with my truffle.js file

Comment: Same problem here, did you find the solution?

Comment: Can u also show us the your migration file?

Answer (score 0):

In truffle.js (or truffle-config.js) under the ropsten provider, try passing the Infura API URL with **https://**. So it should look like this:

```
// Inside truffle.js
  ...

module.exports = {
  networks: {

      ...

    ropsten: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/my-key")
      },
      network_id: 3,
      gas: 4000000      //make sure this gas allocation isn't over 4M, which is the max
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case the problem was that I was using a wrong API key. In you Infura dashboard check if you are using the correct one, the one for the Ropsten network.

And as jfviray said pass the Infura API url with https.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case, that someone has manually configured *truffle migrations directory* in `truffle.config.js` file and now `truffle` is not able to detect the `migrations` directory properly:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  migrations_directory: "truffle-migraitons/",
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by degrading node version to **LTS version**

just uninstall your node and install the LTS version

```
truffle migrate --network ropsten
```